# PHP data import from Excel with wrong encoding

Tags: php, mysql, excel, encoding, utf-8

I have a table in my DB `Person(id, name, last_name, phone_number)`. From time to time I recieve an .xls file containing an updated list of people I need to include in my DB. This file contains some Polish letters like `ą ę ś ć ź ż ł ó`.

When I want to `echo` each line from .xls file, the names are displayed correctly, but when I send a query like `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE last_name = LAST_NAME_FROM_XLS` and this name contains any of those Polish letters, it can't find it.

Now the DB is encoded with utf8 and the .xls file seems to be encoded with iso-8859-2. I tried to use `iconv` to convert from iso-8859-2 to utf8, but it didn't work. How can I encode names from .xls so that DB could see them?

Comment: insert into Person(name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES (CONVERT(xls_name) USING utf8,CONVERT(xls_last_name) USING utf8,CONVERT(xls_phone_number) USING utf8)

Comment: @Pundit I need to use `SELECT` first and this `CONVERT (X) USING utf8` doesn't work when I use it after `WHERE`